# Create new variable based on other columns using R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a huge file where I want to create a column based on other columns. 
My file look like this:

```
person = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
father = c(0,0,1,1,4,5,5,7)
mother = c(0,0,2,3,2,2,6,6)
ped = data.frame(person,father,mother)
```

And I want to create a column indicating if the person is a father or mother (gender column). I got it using a for loop in a small example, but when I apply in the whole file it takes hours to finish. How can I create an apply function to solve that, please. Thanks.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(ped)){
  ped$test[i] = ifelse(ped[i,1] %in% ped[,2], "M", ifelse(ped[i,1] %in% ped[,3], "F", NA)) 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ped <- transform(ped, gender = ifelse(person %in% father,
                                      'M',
                                      ifelse(person %in% mother, 'F', NA)
                                     ))
```

Instead of looping over the individual values across the rows, this uses vectorization.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
ped$gender <- c(NA, 'M', 'F')[as.numeric(factor(with(ped, 
                  1+2*person %in% father + 4*person %in% mother)))]
```

Or a faster option would be to assign `:=` with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ped)[person %in% father, gender:='M'][person %in% mother, gender:='F']
```

Answer (score 2):

Without having to specify each "father" / "mother" / etc option in code, you could do:

```
vars <- c("father","mother")
factor(
  do.call(pmax, Map(function(x,y) (ped$person %in% x) * y, ped[vars], seq_along(vars) )),
  labels=c(NA,"M","F")
)
#[1] M    F    F    M    M    F    M    <NA>
#Levels: <NA> M F
```